# db2 Express-C SAMPLE database

Tags: database, db2

I installed the db2 Express-C in my system. Using the first steps wizard I created the sample database. But i am not able to undertsand what is the userid/password for this sample database created.

Please help.

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default username and password for DB2 express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485085/default-username-and-password-for-db2-express)

Answer (score 3):

DB2 uses the operating system for authentication.  So, any valid user/password you can use to log in to your system should allow you to connect to and query the sample database.

The DB2 setup utility will ask you for a username and password to use for the administrative ID (a.k.a. the "instance owner"), and it will create these IDs on your system.  The defaults for these IDs: `db2inst1` on Linux/UNIX; `db2admin` on Windows.