# Default username and password for DB2 express

Tags: database, db2

I have installed Db2 express on my local windows machine. Can anyone tell what is the default admin credentials. I have tried following combinations. Nothing works.

username: db2admin
password: db2admin

username: db2admin
password: Password123

Answer (score 5):

Should be your local Windows login

Here's what i read to find that: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/bldforge/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.buildforge.doc%2Ftopics%2Fpreinst_db_db2express_new_db.html

There's this question too - that mentions some ID's that it creates

[db2 Express-C SAMPLE database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964674/db2-express-c-sample-database)

Comment: [The right link to use would be this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0006306.html)